# How to Connect to a Router Using Putty

Tags: ssh, putty

I am trying to connect to a router directly using Putty. Using the following commands I can connect to terminal servers:

`putty.exe -ssh <IP> p 22 -l <user> -pw <mypassword>`

output `TS#`

using that command, Putty will open directly to TS#, then I input the router name in Putty to go to the router.

output: `routername#`

My question is: how can I connect to the router directly using SSH, using this command:

`putty.exe -ssh <IP> p 22 -l <user> -pw <mypassword>`

What command should I add to so that I am connected directly to router after connecting in terminal servers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-m` flag to execute a script on login.

> **3.8.3.6 -m: read a remote command or script from a file**
>
> The -m option performs a similar function to the ‘Remote command’ box in the SSH panel of the PuTTY configuration box (see section 4.18.1). However, the -m option expects to be given a local file name, and it will read a command from that file.
>
> With some servers (particularly Unix systems), you can even put multiple lines in this file and execute more than one command in sequence, or a whole shell script; but this is arguably an abuse, and cannot be expected to work on all servers. In particular, it is known not to work with certain ‘embedded’ servers, such as Cisco routers.
>
> This option is not available in the file transfer tools PSCP and PSFTP.

via [http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline](http://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline)

Comment: As I understand it, the original command logs you into a shell and you then need to insert a command to get to your router. Use the `-m` flag to execute whatever command it is you use to get to your router.

Comment: i need to go directly to the router, when i use the code above, im on the terminal server then i still need to type the routername to go inside the router, what i want to do is to connect directly to the router, im doing this in a .bat file so after clicking the putty will open and im connected to the router

Comment: Yes, so you use the `-m` flag with the router command, then you can get there in one step. Example: `putty.exe -ssh <IP> p 22 -l <user> -pw <mypassword> -m '<command that takes you to router>'`

Comment: can you give me sir sample command that can take me to the router? my commands are not working, it says 'line has invalid autocommand "routername" '