# correct autocommand to connect to router in putty

Tags: ssh, router, putty

im trying to connect to the router using my putty in a shell with this line of commands

`putty.exe -ssh <IP> p 22 -l <USERNAME> -pw <PASSWORD> -m C:COMMAND.txt`

every time i run, it says "line has invalid autocommmand"

what is the correct command that COMMAND.txt that can takes me to the router?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Connect to a Router Using Putty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305299/how-to-connect-to-a-router-using-putty)

Answer (score 0):

Either you have missed out the dash before the `p`:

```
putty.exe -ssh <IP> -p 22 -l <USERNAME> -pw <PASSWORD> -m C:COMMAND.txt
```

Or (presuming that was a mistake in typing the command into StackOverflow) it may help us if you posted the contents of `C:COMMAND.txt`. Try also using the full path to that file, instead of specifying the drive but not the path.

Comment: oh im sorry, that's `p` only `putty.exe -ssh <IP> p 22 -l <USERNAME> -pw <PASSWORD> -m C:COMMAND.txt` and the contents of `command.txt` is `ssh <routername>`. and now it says, `connection to <routename> aborted: error status 27`. what does it mean?